# In Django, how can the Graphene GraphQL endpoint be protected for API usage?

Tags: python, django, authentication, graphene-django

Graphene provides a GraphQL integration into Django and supplies a view to create a URL endpoint. The question is how can the endpoint be protected for API usage? The [recommend method](https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/authorization/#adding-login-required) is to use a LoginRequiredMixin which is great for logged in users, but not for use as an API.

I've tried integrating it with DRF tokens, but still end up with the session middleware requiring CSRF. The only solution that works is adding a CSRF exempt decorator, but I fear that this opens up a security vulnerability.

```py
# urls.py
path("graphiql/", root_views.SessionGraphQLView.as_view(graphiql=True), name="graphiql"),
path("graphql/", root_views.TokenGraphQLView.as_view(graphiql=False), name="graphql"),


# views.py
class TokenLoginRequiredMixin(AccessMixin):

    """A login required mixin that allows token authentication."""

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """If token was provided, ignore authenticated status."""
        http_auth = request.META.get("HTTP_AUTHORIZATION")

        if http_auth and "Token" in http_auth:
            pass

        elif not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return self.handle_no_permission()

        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name="dispatch")
class TokenGraphQLView(TokenLoginRequiredMixin, GraphQLView):
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]


class SessionGraphQLView(LoginRequiredMixin, GraphQLView):
    pass
```

Comment: *"... but not for use as an API."* I don't understand this, Can you elaborate? What kind of security do you wish to add to the GrpphQL views?

Comment: Basically, is the implementation above safe against CSRF? Otherwise, what is a safe method of securing a POST endpoint without having to use CSRF protection?

Comment: Can I ask whats wrong with csrf? @Moritz

Comment: How can a valid CSRF token be obtained without a logged in session, but with a token authentication? From experience with other APIs only the token is required for authentication, not fetching a CSRF token and then submitting it with the POST request.